# Amazon CloudFront setup with custom domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I have an application which serves assets under the following URL:

```
https://example.com/assets/...
```

Now I want to use Amazon CloudFront to serve these assets with the URL

```
https://cdn.example.com/assets/...
```

---

**The things I have done:**

1. I created a new distribution with the origin of `cdn.example.com`
2. I added a `CNAME` DNS record pointing `cdn.example.com` to `example.com`

---

Now I feel like that configuration does not serve the assets via CloudFront. Instead if I request my CloudFront Domain Name, lets say `dpw02sdffky7p.cloudfront.net`, I get redirected to `example.com`. So it feels like my assets are still being served from my server, just with some redirects in between.

Am I right? What would be the correct configuration to achieve my goal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

while creating cname record in route53, Alias should be given as yes for endpoints like cloudfront, it will resolve the redirection in server side itself.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

https://serverfault.com/questions/419402/similarities-and-differences-between-cname-record-and-route-53-alias-record

Comment: what do I need to do to make it work? I don't get your answer. Alias records only accept IP addresses

Comment: No explanation other than some links